# Bad Minute Error ,errors in crontab file, can't install

Tags: php, cron

This error is being returned

**array(2) { [0]=> string(32) ""/tmp/crontab.txt":0: bad minute" [1]=> string(38) "errors in crontab file, can't install." }**

```
$new_cron = 'MAILTO="" */2  *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/streaming.example.com/index.php admin cron2
            MAILTO="" ##    */2 *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/streaming.example.com/index.php admin cronnew
            MAILTO="" */15  *   *   *   *   /opt/psa/admin/sbin/fetch_url "https://www.example.com/get_aparat_video"
            MAILTO="admin@example.com" */2  *   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/streaming.example.com/index.php admin cron3 > /dev/null
            MAILTO="" 0 0,4,8,12,16,20  *   *   *   /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/mywebsite/index.php admin sitemapcreater index
            MAILTO="" ##    */3 *   *   *   *   /opt/psa/admin/sbin/fetch_url "https://www.example.com/admin/autoactive"
            MAILTO="admin@example.com" */2 *     *  *   *   /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/streaming.example.com/index.php admin cron > /dev/null
            MAILTO="" 0 0   *   *   *   /usr/bin/php5 /var/www/vhosts/example.com/mywebsite/index.php members cron';
```

I don't see any minute mistakes?  How do i solve?

Comment: I don't think Mailto can be at the beginning of each line like that...

Comment: `MAILTO=""` is in the wrong place isn't it? Should be after just before the command if you're intending on setting and environment variable.